# How to enable/disable NIC Rx

Tags: ethernet

My computer has two Ethernet ports for receiving data, and each port has an open socket. The sender also has two Ethernet ports, and they are synchronizing and transmitting the same data.

Based on my understanding, when a UDP socket is open, incoming data is accumulated in the socket buffer. However, I want to be able to receive the same data from the sender at my convenience.

How can I disable and enable the receiving (Rx) of the network interface card (NIC) in my application S/W?

Comment: an UDP socket isn't opened on an Ethernet NIC/port. it's usually opened with an IP address and a port. So I have trouble to understand the setup you're describing or even its goal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to have access to the data received without buffering, then you should tweak the buffering and/or other socket options like blocking, not the Rx. If you turned Rx off, there would be nothing to access.

Read about sockets, for example [IO::Socket](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO::Socket) for Perl.